# Triple Integral Conversion

Tags: calculus

I am trying to understand how is the cylindrical conversion of the rectangular triple integral is true given that the integral calculates the volume inside a paraboloid bounded by $z=25$ (height-wise) and the radius is not constant throughout the height of $z=x^2+y^2$. Basically, I am trying to understand why I don't need to write the limits for $r$ as a function of theta since the radius is not constant throughout the paraboloid?

$$\int_{-\color{red}5}^{\color{red}5} \int_{-\sqrt{\color{red}{25}-z^2}}^{\sqrt{\color{red}{25}-z^2}} \int_{x^2+y^2}^{\color{red}{25}}x \, dz \, dy \, dx$$

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^5 \int_{r^2}^{25} r^2\cos(\theta) \, dz \, dr \, d\theta$$

Comment: Please format your questions with MathJax instead of using pictures. Pictures aren't searchable and might not be as visible with some users. (I replaced the picture with MathJax already, so no need to worry about this for this question - just for the future).

Comment: Is your question about why the limits of $r$ aren't a function of $\theta$ or about why the limits of $r$ aren't a function of $z$? Your last sentence is a bit confusing.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I am a bit confused myself. As to my post, the question is why the limits of r aren't a function of θ since r isn't constant throughout the paraboloid.

Answer (score 1):

As a function of $\theta$, the bounds on $r$ wouldn't change. Think about a slice $d \theta$ of the paraboloid. This cross-section would be a parabola ($z > r^2$). No matter what $\theta$ is, $r$ would go from $0$ to $5$. This picture shows the region of integration for a fixed $\theta$. As you can see, $r$ goes from $0$ to $5$, while $z$ goes from $r^2$ to $25$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! It makes perfect sense now.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to know I helped. If you believe this answers your question, you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark. This gives me a bit of reputation and lets others know that the question is solved.